# How to achieve pure “Object Oriented” approach with “SIGNAL” and “SLOT” in “Qt C++ Framework”?

Tags: jquery, c++, qt

I know that, in **html**, if I make a **“button”** with **“id=button1”**, then, using **"jQuery"**, I can assign a **“click”** event to that “button1” like this:

```
$(‘button1’).click( function (e) {
      alert(“I was clicked.”);
});
```

This is a **pure** **“Object Oriented”** approach with jQuery, which is so exciting to use.

How can I also achieve that same pure “Object Oriented” approach in **“Qt C++ Framework”** with **“SIGNAL”** and **“SLOT”**?

For example, how can I achieve something like this in Qt:

```
Qt(‘button1’).click( function (e) {
      mainWindow.close();
});
```

Comment: C++11 and lambdas  allow you to embed functions, maybe that is the way to go.

Comment: Not sure why your example (html/jquery) would count as pure "Object Oriented".

Comment: I mean in my html/jquery, the “button1” was an object, and it had an action called “click”, and when that action is triggered something happens. So, the html/jquery is like a pure "Object Oriented" approach because of the way they deal with the “button1”.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the object must be retrievable by `objectName` and not lvalue?

Comment: Qt is an Object-Oriented framework. It is not JavaScript. If you want a button, there is the object QPushButton, which inherits from QObject (inheritance being a core concept of OO). This provides the connect function for signals and slots. Perhaps you'd be better learning how to do things the Qt way and not expect it to conform to javascript. That being said, I agree with @Raistmaj, that C++11 allows you to connect to a lamda function, which uses the inherited connect functionality of QObject and is likely to be the closest to the example in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object-Orientation by default doesn't include "signal&slot" or any event driven ideas:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming

It would not be very beneficial to try and completely copy the design ideas from html/jquery into c++/qt as they are different tools and using them exactly the same might not be the best idea.

**Firstly signals and slots**

Slots are how you create your "actions" for your objects.
(just google "Qt 5 Signals and slots")

so you can have:

```
class mainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
 Q_OBJECT
public slots: 
  void clickedButton()
  {
     qDebug() << "Click action!";
  }
}
```

after this you can link your button's click signal with this slot with connect:

```
connect(myButton,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SLOT(clickedButton())
```

See QPushButton help.

This is the standard way of using Qt and I suggest reading some Qt tutorials and/or documentation if this is not clear.

**Finding elements by name**

If you want to be able to find created buttons by "string" rather than just use pointers/references like normal C++.

My suggestion would be to create:

```
QMap<QString,QPushButton*>
```

and each time a new button is created put it in that map.
The map can then be used to retrieve buttons by "string".

If you want to handle not only buttons but different types of objects to connect to you can use:

```
QMap<QString,QObject*>
```